# Get space between footer and bottom of page blogger

Tags: css, footer, blogger

for some reason my Blogger page won't let me create transparent space between my footer and the bottom of the page. I would like the footer to moved up (tried both margin and padding, but nothing) so that the background is seen for about 10px but need help with what code to use! Please help, thanks!

Link to blog: http://thewordswecarve.blogspot.ie/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this to your css.

```
.content-cap-bottom.cap-bottom {
    height: 10px;
}
```

This will make sure this div stays 'open' so you can see the background below it.

Answer (score 0):

In you css sheet add this:

```
body { margin-bottom: 10px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I inspected your page and added this to `.content-inner`

```
.content-inner {
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

And it seemed to work fine.